# Show all equal values from table inside same div

Tags: php, html, mysql

This code gets all values from a table and for each row it shows its details inside a alert div and i can click a "order ready button" for that single product.

What I need to do is put in a single div all the products that are from the same order, and for that I'm thinking about using all the rows that have the same date value and when this value changes create a new div.

```
            <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM kitchen");

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $table = $row['table'];
                $customer = $row['customer'];
                $product = $row['product_name'];
                $code = $row['product_code'];
                $size = $row['size'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $date = $row['date'];

// It would have to open here in each first distinct $date
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="'.$code.'">';
                echo '<h4>'.'Table '.$table.'</h4>';
                echo '<h4>'.'Name: '.$name.'</h4>';


// Repeat this for each equal $date value
                if($code=="A01"||$code=="A02"||$code=="A03"||$code=="A04"){
                echo '<h4>'.$code.' - '.$product.' ('.$size.')'.'</h4>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<h4>'.$code.' - '.$product.'</h4>';
                }

// Close here before each next distinct $date
                echo '<form action="actionkitchen.php" method="post">';
                echo "<button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' name='data' value='$data' type='submit'>Order Ready</button>";
                echo '</form>';
                echo '</div>';      
            }
         ?>
```

Comment: There are numerous ways of achieving this but the easiest would be to add an ORDER BY clause to your query statement. That way all products for the same order will be listed together

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, not the most elegant solution but it's working.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM kitchen");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $table[] = $row['table'];
        $name[] = $row['name'];
        $product[] = $row['product_name'];
        $code[] = $row['product_code'];
        $size[] = $row['size'];
        $date[] = $row['date'];     
    }

    $count = array_count_values($date);
    $y = 0;

    foreach ($count as $item){         
        for($i=0;$i<$item;$i++){
            if($i==0){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info">';
                echo '<h4>'.'Table '.$table[$y].'</h4>';
                echo '<h4>'.'Name: '.$name[$y].'</h4>';
            }
            if($code[$y]=="A01"||$code[$y]=="A02"||$code[$y]=="A03"||$code[$y]=="A04"){
            echo '<h4>'.$code[$y].' - '.$product[$y].' ('.$size[$y].')'.'</h4>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<h4>'.$code[$y].' - '.$product[$y].'</h4>';
            }
            if($i==$item-1){
                echo '<form action="actionkitchen.php" method="post">';
                echo "<button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' name='data' value='$data[$y]' type='submit'>Order Ready</button>";
                echo '</form>';
                echo '</div>';  
            }
            $y++;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set your products in the same order, I would group them by the key in an array. For our purposes, we'll use a [multidimensional array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) so that we can add our products within the unique key (using "date" in the example). Below you will see me set the array, fetch the rows from the database (sorting by our group key so that we have some consistency on the front end) and begin placing them in their unique groups. When pushing a product into the date array, I am using [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) in combination of [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to set the "product string" within the HTML.

```
<?php
    /* Fetch/Set Kitchen */
    $kitchen    = array();
    $sql        = "SELECT * FROM `kitchen` ORDER BY `date`";
    $query      = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $kitchen[$row['date']][] = array_merge($row, array(
            'product_string' => (in_array($row['product_code'], array('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04')) !== FALSE)
                ? $row['product_code'] . ' - ' . $row['product_name'] . ' (' . $row['size'] . ')'
                : $row['product_code'] . ' - ' . $row['product_name']
        ));
    }
?>
```

To keep our HTML tidy and readable apart from our PHP, you'll see that I've chosen to use an [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for the control structures. This helps by using tab indentations from having put any awkwardly placed curly brackets in our code.

```
<?php foreach($kitchen as $date => $items): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="<?php echo $date; ?>">
        <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
            <h4>Table <?php echo $item['table']; ?></h4>
            <h4>Name: <?php echo $item['customer']; ?></h4>
            <h4><?php echo $item['product_string']; ?></h4>
            <form action="actionkitchen.php" method="POST">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="data" value="<?php echo $item['data']; ?>" type="submit">Order Ready</button>
            </form>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above reference code will output HTML similar to:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="2016-10-21">
    <h4>Table Table 1</h4>
    <h4>Name: Name 1</h4>
    <h4>XXX1 - Product 1 (XXX)</h4>
    <form action="actionkitchen.php" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="data" value="XXX1" type="submit">Order Ready</button>
    </form>
    <h4>Table Table 2</h4>
    <h4>Name: Name 2</h4>
    <h4>XXX2 - Product 2</h4>
    <form action="actionkitchen.php" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="data" value="XXX2" type="submit">Order Ready</button>
    </form>
    <h4>Table Table 3</h4>
    <h4>Name: Name 3</h4>
    <h4>XXX3 - Product 3 (XXX)</h4>
    <form action="actionkitchen.php" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="data" value="XXX3" type="submit">Order Ready</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="2016-10-27">
    <h4>Table Table 4</h4>
    <h4>Name: Name 4</h4>
    <h4>XXX4 - Product 4</h4>
    <form action="actionkitchen.php" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="data" value="XXX4" type="submit">Order Ready</button>
    </form>
    <h4>Table Table 5</h4>
    <h4>Name: Name 5</h4>
    <h4>XXX5 - Product 5 (XXX)</h4>
    <form action="actionkitchen.php" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="data" value="XXX5" type="submit">Order Ready</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="2016-11-06">
    ...etc.
```